# uwsgi inside callable file module import error

Tags: python, nginx, uwsgi

I am implementing uwsgi with nginx and I use this structure for my files in my app directory:

> myappfolder / my_app
>
> myappfolder / my_app / main.py
>
> myappfolder / my_app_venv
>
> myappfolder / wsgi.py

I have set up a python virtualenv for holding my app and installed uwsgi inside of it (following by the tutorial at the https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-python-wsgi-applications-using-uwsgi-web-server-with-nginx)

In the beginning with the default setting as mentioned in that link the server worked fine and I ran uwsgi with this command: `uwsgi --socket 127.0.0.1:12345 -w wsgi &`, but after some tweaking the code in `wsgi.py` file and making it this way:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
sys.path.append('/root/myappfolder')

from my_app.main import Main

fff = Main()

def application(env, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/html')])
    return [fff.sayHello(), str(env)]
```

Then when I run uwsgi it gives me error from the python interpreter => `ImportError: No module named my_app.main`

In `my_app / main.py` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

class Main:
    def sayHello(self):
        return("hello world!")
```

What is the cause of the problem?

***UPDATE 1:** Even after `import sys` in the `wsgi.py` file and using `sys.path.append('the path to myappfolder')` it does not have any effect at all.*

**Question Simplified:** Let me simplify my question: why virtualenv's python interpreter does not find the modules that are alongside the callable file that is used for uwsgi (in my case `wsgi.py` file)?

**UPDATE 2:** I moved `main.py` file from `my_app` folder to one upper path meaning it is now located at `myappfolder / main.py` and now the `wsgi.py` file can *see* and *import* it. Why when it was under a subdirectory, it was not being seen by `wsgi.py` file?

Answer (score 3):

I finally found what was going on. **uwsgi** is using Python 2.7 which requires you to use **__init__.py** file in each folder module. Even an empty file. The problem is fixed now moving from that directory structure mentioned in the question to the one written below:

```
myappfolder / my_app

myappfolder / my_app / main.py

myappfolder / my_app / __init__.py      # empty file

myappfolder / my_app_venv

myappfolder / wsgi.py
```

This is the big difference of python 2.X and 3.X which caused me get stuck for nearly two days.